# Display two different types of attributes, in same dataset, as pie charts in different colours?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, symbology

Is there a python script or something (maybe there is a simpler way) to display data of the same shapefile as a pie chart but as different coloured pie charts?

For example I have road links and intersections in the dataset, with the same 7 different attributes columns which I use to make the pie charts, but instead of creating two separate shapefiles I want them to display the data in the same way but in different colours. So blue colour palette pie chart for intersections and yellow colour palette pie chart for links and no fiddling around with "why is a 5000 count pie chart smaller in links but the 2000 count pie chart in intersection is bigger" - would like the consistency.

Comment: ArcMap can display pie charts on features using values from multiple attributes. Have you searched the help for “pie chart”?